# How to tell if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ne^{-n^2}}{e^{-n}+4}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ne^{-n^2}}{e^{-n}+4} $$

Trying to figure out if this converges, trying to use the divergence test but I can't figure out how to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One has, for $n \geq1$,
$$
0\leq\frac{ne^{-n^2}}{e^{-n}+4}\leq ne^{-n^2}.
$$

Comment: ah, I see how to do it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon You are welcome. Observe that $ne^{-n^2}\leq e^{-n}$ and $0<e^{-1}<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$a_n:=\frac{ne^{-n^2}}{e^{-n}+4}=\frac{ne^n}{4e^{n^2+n}+e^{n^2}}\implies$$

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{\sqrt[n]n\,e}{\sqrt[n]{4e^{n^2+n}+e^{n^2}}}\le\frac{\sqrt[n]n}{e^n}e\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

so the series converges.